# css dropdown menu glitch

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

i recently changed the design of this webpage but now my dropdown menu lists the "hidden" items vertically instead of horizontally even though i use the inline-block display option.

this is the html code from my menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li id="bordered"><a href="index.html">News</a></li>
            <li id="bordered"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li id="bordered"><a href="research.html">Research</a>    </li>
            <li id="bordered"><a href="artists.html">Artists</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="bordered"><a href="">1234 1234</a></li>
                    <li id="bordered"><a href="">1234 1234</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="municipalities.html">Municipalities</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="bordered"><a href="">1234567</a></li>
                    <li id="bordered"><a href="">1234</a>    </li>
                </ul></li>
            <li>
                <form  id="searchbox" action=" " method=" ">
                <input type="text" name="search" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
/*header navigation menu*/
/*STYLING*/
#menu{
margin-top:2px;
font-size:0.8em;
list-style:none;
}
#menu li{
padding:1% 1.5% 1% 1.5%;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#menu li a{
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-weight:bold;
}
#bordered{
border-right:1px dotted #f9f9f3;
}
/*DROPDOWN*/
#menu li ul{
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
margin:1% 0 0 -2px;
border-top: 1px dotted #f9f9f3;
}
#menu li ul li{
float:left;
white-space:nowrap;
}
#menu li:hover ul, #menu li:active ul{
visibility:visible;
}
```

help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I'd be glad to know if my answer helped you.

Comment: ok so i found the blooper!
i had to assign a width of 100% to the containing "hidden" <ul>...
otherwise the <li>s just wrap to the next line for some reason.

thanks Romain!

Comment: Glad you found ! I tried to help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a `float:left` on `#menu li` instead of a `display:inline-block`

It fixes your problem, and it will work on IE7, when `inline-block` won't.

Also be careful with your `bordered` IDs. You should use classes.

Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9PZH/)

Comment: youre totally right about the misuse of the bordered ID.

the main list shows as horizontal but the dropdown one shows as vertical...

Comment: @user2606163 It is displayed horizontally in my Demo. What browser are you using ?

Comment: chrome latest version.

Comment: i cant use the float:left because my header is all centered.
but even when i do it doesnt work...

this must be something real simple that im missing here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `#menu li ul` a larger width:

```
#menu li ul{
   visibility:hidden;
   position:absolute;
   border-top: 1px dotted #f9f9f3;
   width: 10em;
}
```

and remove **`margin:1% 0 0 -2px;`**

Comment: thank you for your comment,
but i dont want to set the width value because i plan to push more items into that list using JS